# youtube api Error with get request i

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I have just completed a jquery tutorial that allows you to play youtube content through fancy-box. The only thing is the course is from 2014 and is now out of date. When I try running the finish site a get an error 400 referring back to the get request. Can someone please help? below is my jquery get request

```
// Run GET Request on API
$.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search",{
        part: 'snippet, id',
        q: q,
        pageToken: token,
        type:'video',
  key: 'MY_KEY'},
  function(data){
            var nextPageToken = data.nextPageToken;
            var prevPageToken = data.prevPageToken;

            // Log Data
            console.log(data);

            $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
                // Get Output
                var output = getOutput(item);

                // Display Results
                $('#results').append(output);
            });

            var buttons = getButtons(prevPageToken, nextPageToken);

            // Display Buttons
            $('#buttons').append(buttons);
        }
);
```

}